# setChild doesn't work - Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, blocks, best-practice, local

I want to force some block to be a child, so `setchild()` doesn't work !

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="root">
        <block type="type/block" name="grid" as="grid" template="path_to.phtml">
            <action method="setChild"><child>grid</child><alias>grid</alias></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('grid');?> // doesn't work
```

Comment: Can you please add the file name in which you are using the code `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('grid');?>`

Comment: `catalog/product/view.phtml`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure in which file you are using the code `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('grid');?>`

If you are setting child in your root section, then you will **not** be able to get the block in `product/view.phtml` file.

Any child added in `root` will only be get in template files like, **1column.phtml**, **2columns-left.phtml** etc.

If you want to add child in content section, please use `reference` as `content` in your layout xml file.

Comment: To answer you, im using the `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('grid');?>` in `catalog/product/view.phtml` indeed. yes i set it in root and i want to get it there and this view.phtml is setted as 1column. you told that: `Any child added in root will only be get in template files like, 1column.phtml, 2columns-left.phtml etc.` so it should work logically ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="type/block" name="grid" as="grid" template="path_to.phtml">
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Now, call `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('grid');?>`

Here we are adding `grid` block to the content part of the `catalog_product_view`, which then can be called as `getChildHtml()`, since this `grid` block is child of `catalog_product_view`'s content.

This should work for you.

Comment: This will never work, you assign a grid block to the content, so he will be rendred to the content without `getChildHtml( )` because we refer here to the `core/text_list` ! in other word a `structural block`. But what i want to do is to refer my block to the root block and i can call him as `getBlockHtml( )` and it works no doubt but i want to force this block to be a child to call him as `getChildHtml( )` and `<action method="setChild">` exist well in Magento

Answer (score 0):

We can force this block to be a child **in another way** like a code bellow then to call him like `getChildHtml()` but not like what i want : with `<action method="setChild">...`

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="root">
        <block type="type/block" name="some.name" as="some.name" template="path_to_this_template.phtml">    
            <block type="type/block" name="grid" as="grid" template="path_to.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Now i can call my block : `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('grid')?>`